# Dropzone display on whole form even if i use previewsContainer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, dropzone.js

Im try to solve my problem last 2 days and there is no right solution and im really need help.

This is my form:

```
<% simple_form_for @something , html: { class: "form-horizontal dropzone"} do |f| %>
<% f.input :title %>
<% f.input :description %>
<div class="dropzone-previews">
    <div class="fallback">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :uploads do |u| %>
        <%= u.input :attachment, as: :file, multiple: true %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and js:

```
$(function () {
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  var mediaDropzone;
  mediaDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
    maxFiles: 2,
    previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    paramName: "issue[uploads_attributes][][attachment]",
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    clickable: true,
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
    mediaDropzone.on('sending', (file, xhr, formData) => {
       $.each(file.postData, function(k, v){
                formData.append(k, v);
            });
     });
});
```

Upload working properly, everything works except preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved problem. When you put dropzone to form element, it give you extra border on all form. So to set up dropzone preview properly i had to add style to form and set border on element where i want to see dropzone. After that i had to change set up "clickable" on that preview element. So in my case i have used:

in form:

```
<% simple_form_for @something , html: { class: "form-horizontal dropzone" style: "border: 0"} do |f| %>
(...)
<div class="dropzone-previews" style="border-style: dashed;">
(...)
</div>
```

in js:

```
clickable: ".dropzone-previews"
```